# Cloudfront - Stream not Found

Tags: amazon-s3, rtmp, amazon-cloudfront

I'm kind of new to cloudfront but have managed to get JWPlayer working rtmp for a .mov I put in a bucket connected to a streaming distribution. What I'm not sure about is that I've added 2 other .mov files to the same bucket and made them public both with the same permissions (Everyone: Open/View) however the player reports stream not found. Does it take a certain amount of time for the videos uploaded to become accessible via RTMP?

thanks

Comment: I'm just looking into this myself at the moment so I'm not entirely confident but it looks like [streaming of `.mov` files does not work on CloudFront](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=301345).

Comment: I think you are correct there , I resolved this one by using .mp4 files a while ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .mp4 (h.264) files fixed this issue for me.